# Ubuntu server mapping to two domains independently?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns

I have a wordpress blog running on my Ubuntu server. I want it so:

```
domain1.com loads domain1.com in the URL bar
domain2.com loads domain2.com in the URL bar
```

each of these domains points to the same server.

Currently, `domain1.com` redirects to `domain2.com` and I'm not sure why. I've setup ssl on the server using lets encrypt and each of the domains separately point to the proper IP address and DNS name servers. I'm not quite sure what causes the redirect.

Comment: What the web-server configuration, the behavior you describe  seems to me that the web server answer with the default domain always.

Comment: @AtomiX84 is right we could not help you while we do not know anything abut your Apache's configuration.